# Guidance on how to properly update carousel slide increment values for previous and next slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single item carousel has a total of 3 slides which are navigated by clicking the previous and next buttons, each click moves the carousel and adds in slide content from an array.

Basically when you click **`next`** the carousel slides right a value is incremented and the array items read to create the next slide but my increments don't seem to be correct at all. Can someone please advise on where I may be going wrong. Basically i use the math `items[currentPage+1]` and `items[currentPage-1]` to get the next and previous slides but this seems to be incorrect so some of my slides appear as `undefined`

**JS**

```
var items = [
        'http://dummyimage.com/1000x400/00ad8a/ffffff&text=Slide+1',
        'http://dummyimage.com/1000x400/ab6100/ffffff&text=Slide+2',
        'http://dummyimage.com/1000x400/8900ab/ffffff&text=Slide+3',
        'http://dummyimage.com/1000x400/005eab/ffffff&text=Slide+4',
        'http://dummyimage.com/1000x400/ab003c/ffffff&text=Slide+5'],
        currentPage = 0,
        noOfPages = items.length,
        lastPage = noOfPages - 1;

btnNext.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (currentPage === lastPage) {
            currentPage = 0;
        } else {
            currentPage++;
        }

        console.log('Current Page', items[currentPage]);

        //move carousel to right 100%
        carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(-100%)');

        $('.slide:first').insertAfter('.slide:last');

        var nextSlide = currentPage+1;

        //populate .slide:last with item[currentPage+1]
        $('.slide:last').html('<img src="' + items[nextSlide] + '" alt="" class="slide-img fluid">');

        setTimeout(function () {
            resetSlides();
            resetCarousel();

            setTimeout(function () {
                carousel.removeAttr('style').removeClass('expose-left expose-right');
            }, 100);

        }, 500);

    });
```

**Js Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/GKv4p/38/

Comment: It seems to be a 0-based vs. 1-based indexing issue. You're comparing `currentPage` to `noOfPages` instead of `lastPage`. `currentPage` and `lastPage` are 0-based, while `noOfPages` refers to the number of pages, not the index of the last page.

Comment: Hi makla, i updated the noOfPages to lastPage thanks for that! moving through the slides clicking next though when I get to slide 5 instead of moving to slide 1 i get an undefined slide still. any ideas on that?

Comment: yeah, it's a bounds thing again. You aren't checking them when you set `previousSlide` and `nextSlide`. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnoble01/GKv4p/40/).

Comment: Also, the slider is a little buggy if you click either button in quick succession. You may want to remove the click callbacks while slide animations are in progress.